# HP DV4T-1200SE - Integrated webcam not detected by Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, drivers, webcam, hp-laptop

I have an HP Pavilion DV4T-1200SE laptop that originally came with Windows Vista x64. I've since installed Windows 7 x64, and while the laptop runs fine but I positively *cannot* get it to detect the webcam.

I've updated the BIOS, done a forced reset on it (taken out the battery, unplugged it, then held down the power button for 10+ seconds), made sure the chipset drivers are up to date, reset the BIOS to default settings (although there are almost no BIOS options to speak of on this machine), and told the Device Manager to scan for new hardware after each of these - nothing is detected. Nada.

There isn't even an 'Imaging Devices' category in the Device Manager. All hardware shown states that it is running properly and even if I expand all categories there is nothing at all that even hints that it's the webcam. At this points I'm quite certain that it's not detected *at all*, and therefor can't have drivers for it installed because as far as Win7 is concerned it does not exist.

Any ideas? I've run out of my own at this point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you confirm that it ran fine with Vista?

Comment: Yes, the webcam worked fine in Vista.

Comment: Can you make a Linux Live CD and try accessing it from that? I had to do that to troubleshoot my webcam that Windows 8 was refusing to work with. That won't get it to work in Windows 7, but I'm concerned that the device may have completely failed since it's not even showing UP in Device Manager.

Comment: Have you installed [these drivers](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3860512) ? And please comment on the procedures in [this article](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02452221&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&product=3860512#N48).